# How to access internal parameters of Simulink blocks?

Tags: parameters, simulink

Assume you have a Simulink block (e.g. a `delay`) that has a parameter (e.g. `delay length`). You want to be able to set the value of the parameter in one place and use it in different blocks (including the mentioned `delay` block). I can think of two possible implementations:

1. Include a variable `mydelaylength` in an initialisation script. Inside each block, the variable `mydelaylength` is entered instead of a numerical value.
2. Use a common constant that is connected to each block that needs it. This only works with an *input signal*, for instance with multiplication blocks. Is it correct that you cannot do this with *parameters* (such as the `delay length` of a `delay` block)? Or is there a workaround that I do not know yet?

[image]

Comment: There is no such things as an 'external parameter'.  There are `parameters` - these are entered on block dialogs; and there are `signals` - these enter blocks though inports.  There is no workaround for approach (2) because you should be using approach (1).

Comment: @PhilGoddard I see. I edited the question. If this is all there's to say, I invite you to answer the question so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you only mentioned the "Delay" block as an example, but one can select the source of the "delay" parameter (for both "Delay" and "Variable Integer Delay" blocks) to be "Dialog" (option 1 in your question) or "Input Port" (option 2 in your question). This is also true for various other blocks and properties.
A third option is to set the parameter of a block with the "[set_param()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/set_param.html)
" function from the MATLAB workspace.

Comment: Nice, this is what I was looking for. Didn't know it was possible!